# Pandas Resample OHCL

Tags: pandas, pandas-resample

| index | close |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-02-21 | 3 |
| 2022-02-22 | 1 |
| 2022-02-23 | 5 |
| 2022-02-24 | 5 |
| 2022-02-25 | 7 |
| 2022-03-02 | 4 |
| 2022-03-03 | 2 |
| 2022-03-04 | 1 |

My output should be:

| index | close |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-02-21 | 7 |
| 2022-03-02 | 1 |

I have tried

```
df.resample('W-MON', closed='left', label='left').last()
```

but I got a wrong label.

| index | close |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-02-21 | 7 |
| 2022-02-28 | 1 |

The problem is that I could have "missing days", like 2022-02-28 and 2022-03-01 and I would like to use the first "available" day of the week. e.g 2022-02-21 (Monday) and 2022-03-02 (Wednesday)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the index to a new column then keep the first value in this group

```py
out = (df.assign(index=df.index)
       .groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='W-MON', closed='left', label='left')).agg({'index': 'first', 'close': 'last'})
       .reset_index(drop=True))
```

```
print(out)

       index  close
0 2022-02-21      7
1 2022-03-02      1
```